# How to get html content from XWalkView?

Tags: android, html, crosswalk, javascript-injection

I have tried I did in WebView using JavaScriptInterface. But it is not working. How to get HTML content from XWalkView?

In this way I could get HTML from WebView:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://joerichard.net/api/test/generate.htm");
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.endsWith("generate.htm")){
                    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                            "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    class MyJavaScriptInterface {

        private Context ctx;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        public void showHTML(String html) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        }

    }

}
```

I tried the same for XWalkView but have not succeded. How to get HTML source code from XWalkView?

Comment: Could you provide more information about you question? Do you want call java function in js?